# Confusion of the decidability of $(N,s)$

Tags: logic, model-theory

In some context the PA has only the successor operator $'s'$, but in logic we always refer the structure of PA is $(\mathbb{N},0,1,s,+,\times)$. I believed the theory of the two sturctures are equivalent because I believed that $ '+'$and $  '\times'$ are definable in $(\mathbb{N},s)$. Then I concluded that the theory of $(\mathbb{N},s)$ is not decidable.

But now I'm not quite sure about this, in addition, what is the decidability of the theory of $(\mathbb{N},+)$? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Decidable and decidable.

Comment: @AndréNicolas So $'+'$ and $'\times'$ are not definable in $(N,s)$? Are PA axioms for $(N,s)$ complete?

Comment: Am uncertain about Peano axioms, But the set of sentences that only involve $+$ and are **true** in $\mathbb{N}$ is recursive.

Comment: @Chao: Yes, PA axioms are complete for the $(\mathbb{N},s,+)$ fragment. To see this it is enough (because Pressburger arithmetic is complete) to check that the fragment of any PA-model satisfies the sentences in some axiomatization of Pressburger arithmetic (see for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic )

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's a straightforward way to show that $+$ is not definable relative to $\text{Th}(\mathbb{N},s)$.

- $0$ is definable in $\text{Th}(\mathbb{N},s)$, so $\text{Th}(\mathbb{N},s)$ and $\text{Th}(\mathbb{N},s,0)$ have the same definable sets (i.e. any formula in the language $\{s,0\}$ is equivalent to one in the language $\{s\}$ by replacing any occurrence of $0$ with its definition). In particular, it suffices to show that $+$ is not definable in $\text{Th}(\mathbb{N},s,0)$.
- $\text{Th}(\mathbb{N},s,0)$ has quantifier elimination. Showing this is not too hard.
- Now we want to examine all the formulas in three variables ($x$, $y$, $z$) and check that none of them picks out the graph of $+$ (i.e is the formula $x+y=z$). Well, any formula in three variables is equivalent to a boolean combination of atomic formulas. Since the only relation around is $=$, any atomic formula looks like $s^n(a) = s^m(b)$, where $a$ and $b$ are one of $x$, $y$, $z$, or $0$. So any such formula expresses that some variable has a particular value, or that some pair of variables differ in value by some fixed amount. It only takes a bit of thinking to convince yourself that no boolean combination of these can define $+$.

You said in a comment that you only know two ways of showing that something is not definable: decidability arguments and automorphism arguments. It's true that these are the main tricks, but there's a third, more basic way - actually characterizing all the definable sets. This is exactly what quantifier elimination helps us do.

Comment: Nice proof, +1 of course!

Answer (score 6):

The theory of the successor function, and the theory of addition, are both decidable. For details about the theory of addition, please see [Presburger Arithmetic.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic)

Multiplication is **not** definable in Presburger arithmetic.

Comment: Thank you, the only question left is what about the definability of '+' in $(N,s)$?

Comment: Addition is not definable from successor. I would have to think for a while to recall/reconstruct the proof. Definability is a very narrow notion in first-order logic. Note that the answers are completely different in second-order logic.

Comment: How do show that addition is not definable by successor if the theories of them are both decidable?

Comment: Thanks, in fact I only know two methods to prove a relation is not dedinable: by a decibability arguement, or construct a automorphism which does not preserve the relation. Neither works for this case.

Answer (score 5):

Let me address one way (using some powerful machinery, but well-known) to show that addition is not definable in $(\mathbb{N}, s)$. We will see that $(\mathbb{N}, s)$ and $(\mathbb{N}, +)$ have different decidability behaviour with respect the monadic second order language, this is enough.

As others have pointed out it is known that the first-order theory of  $(\mathbb{N}, s)$ is decidable, and the same is true for  $(\mathbb{N}, +)$. On the other hand, it is also a famous result of Buchi the fact that the monadic second order theory of $(\mathbb{N}, s)$ is also decidable (it is worth noticing here that Rabin generalized this result to the full binary tree). On the other hand, it is not difficult to check that multiplication $\cdot$ is definable in the monadic second order theory of $(\mathbb{N}, +)$; as a hint I suggest to first show that the binary divisibility relation "$a | b$" is definable. Thus, from the undecidability of the first-order theory of  $(\mathbb{N}, +, \cdot)$ it follows that it is also undecidable the monadic second order theory of $(\mathbb{N}, +)$.

Comment: Thanks I admit that I have never heard 'monadic second order logic' before, I can't find its definition on wiki, but I'm quite interested. Can you give some reference on this subject?

Comment: @Chen: Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_logic , and then you can read the following "old" survey by Gurevich http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pl/1235417279