# Can we make recursion into an axiom schema?

Tags: logic, peano-axioms

The language of second-order arithmetic is (by definition) generated by a constant symbol $0$ and a unary function $S$. However, first-order arithmetic (hereafter $\mathrm{PA}$) famously requires a $+$ symbol and a $\times$ symbols.

> **Question.** Can we eliminate the need to take $+$ and $\times$ as primitive in $\mathrm{PA}$, by replacing the "axiom schema of induction" with something stronger? I mean a schema guaranteeing that **primitive recursion always defines a unique function.**

I feel like this is impossible in a first-order language.

But if it *is* possible, it means we can define $+$ in the obvious way:

1. $\forall xy.(x+Sy) = S(x+y)$
2. $\forall x.x+0 = x$

Similarly with $\times$.

I know that [PRA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_arithmetic) already does something like this, but that is *much* weaker than $\mathrm{PA}.$ I want something equal to $\mathrm{PA}$ in its power. I also don't want to start out with infinitely many function symbols like $\mathrm{PRA}$ does. Just $S$.

Comment: PRA is only weaker than PA because the induction scheme is omitted. If we add that to PRA we obtain a theory that is equivalent to PA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is known that addition is not definable in the structure $(\mathbb{N},0,S)$ by any first-order formula. There is a sketch [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/313612/confusion-of-the-decidability-of-n-s/313749#313749).  The same holds for multiplication, with a small variation of the proof.

That structure satisfies *all* true sentences of its language. So even if we took all those sentences as axioms, we still would not be able to define addition.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\Sigma$ be the signature with a constant $0$ and a unary operation $S$ and let $(X, 0, S)$ be a $\Sigma$-structure. Fix a subset $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \coprod_{k \ge 0} (X^{X^k} \times X^{X^{2+k}})$ and say that $(X, 0, S)$ has **primitive recursion** with respect to $\mathcal{F}$ if, for every $(g, h) \in X^{X^k} \times X^{X^{2+k}}$, there is a *unique* $f  : X^{1+k} \to X$ such that $f (0, \vec{x}) = g (\vec{x})$ and $f (S(t), \vec{x}) = g (t, f(t, \vec{x}), \vec{x})$.

**Lemma.** Let $k = 0$, let $g : X^0 \to X$ be given by $g () = 0$, and let $h : X^2 \to X$ be given by $h (t, y) = y$. If $(g, h) \in \mathcal{F}$ and $(X, 0, S)$ has primitive recursion with respect to $\mathcal{F}$, then $(X, 0, S)$ satisfies the second-order induction axiom (for unary predicates).

*Proof.* Let $P \subseteq X$ and define $f : X \to X$ by $f (x) = 0$ if $x \in P$ and $f (x) = 1$ if $x \notin P$. Suppose $0 \in P$ and for all $x \in P$, $S (x) \in P$. Then $f (0) = g ()$ and $f (S(t)) = f (t, p (t))$, so by hypothesis, $f$ must be the constant function with value $0$. Hence $P = X$, as required. 　◼

You might object that there is nothing that guarantees the existence of the function $f : X \to X$ constructed in the proof, but let us assume the metatheory lets us do that. Note that the functions $g : X^0 \to X$ and $h : X^2 \to X$ are definable in the $\Sigma$-language, and I imagine it is reasonable to assume that the primitive recursion scheme at least includes primitive recursion with respect to $\Sigma$-definable functions.

A more serious objection is that I have not specified what it means for a function $f : X^{1+k} \to X$ to exist in the first place. So perhaps one should also specify a subset $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \coprod_{k \ge 0} X^{X^k}$ of admissible functions or something like that. Then what we have starts to resemble Henkin semantics for second order logic.

Regardless, I think the moral is clear: in second order logic (with reasonable assumptions about the construction of predicates/functions), primitive recursion (in the sense above) is equivalent to the full induction principle. (To deal with $n$-ary predicates for $n > 1$, we need to assume a little bit more about $\mathcal{F}$.)